# Web Form: Dynamically populate hidden field from query string (or other method)

Tags: forms

I usually use Google forms/sheets to gather customer info, but I have come accross a situation that Google forms can't seem to handle. There seems to be no way to create a hidden field.

---

**Specifications:**
I need a user friendly webform (like Google forms/sheets) with the ability to create a custom ID field and populate that field dynamically.

---

One possibility is that `www.myform.com/thisform/?custom_id=1234` would populate the hidden `custom_id` field with value `1234`. I'm fine with other population methods as well.

I can certainly create my own webpage/form, but I'm creating this and handing it off to a less tech savy client. Thus the need for a prebuilt online form solution.

Do you know of any GoogleForm-like webform with the ability to populate hidden fields as described above?

Answer (score 0):

For doing that I think you should take the help of jquery and ajax. Every time after clicking a button a input field will be generated and each row will contain a hidden id

Comment: I can certainly make my own form without issue, but I'm looking for a pre-made webform (like Google forms) that I can hand off to a non-coder to manage.